# Changing breadcrumbs product name to an attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

I would like to change the output of the breadcrumbs to be an attribute instead of the product name.

**Example:**

`Home -> Category -> Product Name` would become `Home -> Category -> Magento_Attribute`

I have tracked down 2 places where the breadcrumbs are generated:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php`

```
/**
 * Retrieve current Product object
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product|null
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return Mage::registry('current_product');
}
```

and
`/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml`

I've been playing around with both files not having much luck.

How do I change the default behavior of the breadcrumbs product name to and attribute?

Comment: Had you already time to test my sugeestion?

Comment: yes - sorry for the delay

Comment: Sorry for repeated question :) But when I spent my time, getting some feedback is always nice ... even when my answer is wrong. So, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` event to change breadcrumbs ...

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    <observers>
        <some_alias>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>setProductBreadcrumb</method>
        </some_alias>
    </observers>
</core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

In `Observer.php` set your own value for `product` crumb:

```
public function setProductBreadcrumb(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
     $block = $observer->getBlock();
     if ($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs) {
         if ($product = Mage::registry('current_product')) {
             $block->addCrumb('product', array(
                 'label'    => $product->getSku(),
                 'title'    => $product->getSku(),
             ));
         }
     }
}
```

For modifing category crumbs you can use `$block->addCrumb('category{id}', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

in `/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml`
Replace

`<strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>`

with below code

```
<strong>
    <?php
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if($product){
        echo $product->getWeight();
    }else
    {
        echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']);
    }   
    ?>
</strong>
```

and use your `attributecode` name instead of `weight` in `getWeight`

Comment: there is no `<strong>`, I tried in `<span>` no luck